# extractThumbnail generate unknown bitmap configuration error

Tags: android, image-manipulation

I'm trying to generate a thumbnail form an image resource, using the method:

```
ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(Bitmap src, int width, int height);
```

But when I do so, I get the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown bitmap configuration
```

Here is my code:

```
// get a scaled down version of the image resource, to avoid loading
// the full image into memory
Bitmap im1 = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(context.getResources(),
                R.drawable.im1, 
                R.dimen.thumbnail_width,
                R.dimen.thumbnail_height);

Bitmap thumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(im1,
                     R.dimen.thumbnail_width,
                     R.dimen.thumbnail_height);

holder.picture.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
```

The error pops at the line where the method `extractThumbnail` is called.

The method `decodeSampledBitmapFromResource` is the one described here:
https://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

The image is a "JPEG" image of size 680x1024, weighting 183Ko.

I have tried to use instead the method:

```
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap src, int dstWidth, int dstHeight, boolean filter);
```

But I get the same error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may be having issues because you are passing in the id's of your resources instead of the actual values those id's represent. Try adding

```
int height = (int)context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.thumbnail_height);
int width = (int)context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.thumbnail_width);
```

and now modify your code to read like this.

```
// get a scaled down version of the image resource, to avoid loading
// the full image into memory
Bitmap im1 = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(context.getResources(),
                R.drawable.im1, 
                width,
                height);

Bitmap thumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(im1,
                     width,
                     height);
```